# Strange Integer output from csv.reader in VSCODE Run Selected Line in Python Terminal

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a Python script to format a CSV file containing Japanese vocabulary into Logseq's card format. It is a simple script that works as expected, but whenever I run it, it outputs some weird integers.

```bash
9
12
6
12
5
11
7
12
9
```

The Script is just:

```py
import csv
import pathlib
import logging

filePath = pathlib.Path(r"C:\logseq\pages\新出単語.md")

with open(filePath,"w",encoding='utf-8') as export_file:
    with open('source.csv',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as wordcsv:
        spamreader = csv.reader(wordcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in spamreader:
            export_file.write(f"- #card {row[0]}\n")
            try:
                export_file.write(f"\t- {row[1]}\n")
            except IndexError:
                logging.warning(f"Missing Second Column,{row[0]} has no second column")
```

The CSV file is like:

```
一生,いっしょう
思い出,おもいで
開く,ひらく
作る,つくる
大好評,だいこうひょう
期間中,きかんちゅう
主催,しゅさい
協定校,きょうていこう
久しぶり,ひさしぶり
```

The script works just fine, the integer output is not much of a problem.
But as the length of my CSV file grows, they push warning messages off the screen. That is kind of annoying.

If I just run the Python file from a terminal like `python cardgen.py`, no weird integers at all.

But if I run it via `shift + enter` in VSCode (From vscode-python plugin, run python, run selected line in python terminal), I have those strange integers. What is the problem here?

Comment: This code isn't printing those integers.  It must be coming from other code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: This code only writes to the export file, it doesn't print anything on the screen. And `csv` doesn't parse integers in the file, it just returns a list of strings.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VSCode, but you appear to be running your code in a way equivalent to a Python interactive interpreter - which automatically prints any non-None result from an expression.  And the only such expressions in your code are the calls to `.write()`, which return the number of bytes written.  *Those* are the numbers you're seeing.

Comment: I ran your code in VSCode and nothing prints.  @jasonharper's theory sounds correct, but don't know why the numbers are printing.  Must be something to do with your VSCode configuration.

Comment: @JohnGordon This code is literally the whole Python file.

Comment: @jasonharper Thx! This sounds like exactly what is happening. Let me try it in PyCharm's interactive interpreter

Comment: I am trying to use `len(line.encode('utf-8'))` to get the bytes of written lines, but they do not match.

Comment: But they are indeed relevant to the text being written. The integers change when i change the content of the string

Comment: I can reproduce the issue (*in a certain configuration*) with [Jupyterlab](https://jupyter.org/). From what I can see (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJVaR.png), those strange integers are the number of characters per each line in the output (*which is here* `新出単語.md` ).